# Node.js : How to do error handing in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with AWS Lambda, API Gateway. Language is Node.js.

Please check the below code. There I am accepting a parameter called `id` then get data from the database and return back as the response.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : prop.get('server.host'),
  user     : prop.get("server.username"),
  password : prop.get("server.password"),
  port     : prop.get("server.port"),
  database : prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.getMilestoneStatusByID = (event, context, callback) => {

  const { id } = event.queryStringParameters;
  console.log("id", id);

  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "select * from milestone_status where idmilestone_status = ?";
  con.execute(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify(result),
      "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
  });
};
```

However, in any case the `id` is null or no parameter provided, then the user gets the standard AWS error output, `"message": "Internal server error"`. But what I need is to pass 404 status code, with the message `Missing Parameters`.

I tried to put the whole block inside the `handler` into a `try-catch` and tried to fire the following code inside the `catch`

```
var response = {
      "statusCode": 404,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify("Missing Parameters"),
      "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
```

But non of these stopped me from getting the standard AWS error message, `"message": "Internal server error"`.

How can I implement the error that I am looking for?

Comment: Do you even see a lambda invocation in those cases? Does the api gateway already reject the request? *If* the code is actually executed you should not put it inside a try-catch but instead check if `id` is given and then reply accordingly.

Comment: @luk2302: When the code is in try catch, the `catch `never got executed. It is like the `response` is stuck, because the `POSTMAN` was keep on running without a response. You are correct. Can you give me a code sample on fixing this up please?

Comment: @luk2302: Anyway, I actually tried checking whether the ID is null by trying `if(!id)` but the default error was triggered anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The issue was not with the returning of the error, but with the `null` check. This worked.

exports.getMilestoneStatusByID = (event, context, callback) => {

```
const params = event.queryStringParameters;

if (!params || params.id == null) {
    var response = {
        "statusCode": 404,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify({ error: "Missing Parameters" }),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
} else {
    const { id } = params;
    // ...
}
```